# Sencha ExtJS 5 with ASP.NET MVC - Save Model via Proxy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I've just started playing with Sencha ExtJS 5 with ASP.NET Web API.

One of the basic examples is creating a model and posting data to "proxy".

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-proxy

My ExtJS proxy is posting to ASP.NET Web API which is expecting NULL value in the Id column in-order to insert to db as new record.

The problem is that ExtJS "create" function auto generates a string id (for example SessionModel-1) to the model id column.

I've attached a screenshot of the save request payload.

[image]

```
 Ext.define("SessionModel", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'approved', type: 'bool' , defaultValue : false }
        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: '/api/Session'

        }

    });

    var mySession1 = Ext.create("SessionModel", {
        title: 'C++',
        approved: true,
    });


  mySession1.save();
```

Session.cs - Model is defined :

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Session
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Approved { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SessionController.cs - Controller POST :

```
 // POST api/Session
[ResponseType(typeof(Session))]
public IHttpActionResult PostSession(Session session)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Sessions.Add(session);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = session.Id }, session);
}
```

[image]
**How can i stop ExtJS from auto generating the id or what is the correct way to use "save" ?**

Comment: set session.Id = 0 before ModelState check...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, extjs is populating [idProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty) because they need it for internal things. If you want to set your id propererty on the client side before it goes to the server you should create custom proxy class and override [buildRequest](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-buildRequest). In there you can check if desired action is `create` and set [idProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty) accordingly.

```
buildRequest: function(operation) {
    var request = this.callParent(arguments);

    if (request.getAction() === 'create') {
        request.getRecords().forEach(function(record) {
            record.set('carId', ''); //assing desired value 
        });
    }

    return request;
}
```

Here is a nice [post about custom proxies](http://skirtlesden.com/articles/custom-proxies) from Skirtle.